# How to do self join on min/max

Tags: sql, inner-join, self, minmax

I am new to sql queries.
Table is defined as

```
(  symbol varchar,
   high int,
   low int,
   today date,
   Primary key (symbol, today)
)
```

I need to find for each symbol in a given date range, `max(high)` and `min(low)` and corresponding dates for `max(high)` and `min(low)`.

- Okay to get first max date and min date in given table.
- In a given date range some dates may be missing. If start date is not present then next date should be used and if last date is not present then earlier available date should be used

Data is for one year and around 5000 symbols.

I tried something like this

```
SELECT a.symbol,
       a.maxValue,
       a.maxdate,
       b.minValue,
       b.mindate
FROM (
    SELECT table1.symbol, max_a.maxValue, max_a.maxdate
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT table1.symbol,                            
               max(table1.high) AS maxValue, 
               table1.TODAY AS maxdate
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY table1.symbol
    ) AS max_a  
    ON max_a.symbol = table1.symbol
    AND table1.today = max_a.maxdate
) AS a  
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT symbol,
           min_b.minValue,
           min_b.mindate 
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT symbol,
               min(low) AS minValue, 
               table1.TODAY AS mindate
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY testnsebav.symbol
    ) AS min_b
    ON min_b.symbol = table1.symbol
    AND table1.today = min_b.mindate
) AS b
ON a.symbol = b.symbol
```

Comment: which sql server... SQL-Server, MySQL,...

Answer (score 0):

The first INNER query pre-qualifies for each symbol what the low and high values are within the date range provided.  After that, it joins back to the original table again (for same date range criteria), but also adds the qualifier that EITHER the low OR the high matches the MIN() or MAX() from the PreQuery.  If so, allows it in the result set.

Now, the result columns.  Not knowing which version SQL you were using, I have the first 3 columns as the "Final" values.  The following 3 columns after that come from the record that qualified by EITHER of the qualifiers.  As stocks go up and down all the time, its possible for the high and/or low values to occur more than once within the same time period.  This will include ALL those entries that qualify the MIN() / MAX() criteria.

```
select
      PreQuery.Symbol,
      PreQuery.LowForSymbol,
      PreQuery.HighForSymbol,
      tFinal.Today as DateOfMatch,
      tFinal.Low as DateMatchLow,
      tFinal.High as DateMatchHigh
   from
      ( select
              t1.symbol,
              min( t1.low ) as LowForSymbol,
              max( t1.high ) as HighForSymbol
           from 
              table1 t1
           where
              t1.today between YourFromDateParameter and YourToDateParameter
           group by
             t1.symbol ) PreQuery
      JOIN table1 tFinal
         on PreQuery.Symbol = tFinal.Symbol
        AND tFinal.today between YourFromDateParameter and YourToDateParameter
        AND (   tFinal.Low = LowForSymbol
             OR tFinal.High = HighForSymbol )
```